# Two Model in one view asp.net mvc 4 not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have two models within my model folder called Models, i am trying to pull data from the model to display it in the view, i am aware of only one model statement can be applied to the view. So i have Created a ViewModels which contain the properties that i would like to reference in the view. now when i run the the application im getting a compilation Error which says:

> "Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Models' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

View Models Code

```
public class MainModelscs <T> where T :class
{
    public StoreAudit StoreAudit { get; set; }
    public StoreQuestions StoreQuestions { get; set; }

    public IPagedList<T> IndexList { get; set; }

}
```

model properties in view

```
@model PopMarketing.ViewModel.MainModelscs<Models>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full namespace of the Models type which you are using. Something like this:

```
 @model PopMarketing.ViewModel.MainModelscs<PopMarketing.Models.ListItemType>
```

Comment: thanks i have tried your solution but it still dont work